# Jekyll: check if post content empty

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I have a series of posts in a Jekyll project where some of have just a title and some have a title and content. I want to do different things with the post in each case. For example:

```
{% for post in site.categories.publications %}
    {{ post.title }}
    {% if post.content == "" or post.content == nil or post.content == blank %}
        <p>Nothing here.</p>
    {% else %}
        {{ post.content }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But the `if` statement doesn't actually catch the empty posts. I based my conditions on [this page](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/223), but none of the 3 possibilities catch the empty posts. Any ideas on how to handle these posts?

Comment: Did you try testing for content instead? `if post.content != nil`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure that you have nothing after your front matter

```
---
---
NO NEW LINE HERE !!
```

No spaces, no new lines

Sometimes text editors will add a newline at the end of the file.
You can get rid of that with:

```
{% assign content = post.content | strip_newlines %}
```

and then test with:

```
{% if content == ""  %}
```

Comment: Awesome! I'd never thought about hacking the `{{ content }}` variable with the `| strip_newlines` filter to achieve this. Thanks!